# Looking for information about inventor of us20050211962

Tags: licensing, patent-lifetime, ownership, us20050211962

How can I reach the inventor of this patent application?

Patent Application: us20050211962

Looking for a phone number or email address to ask implementation details about the invention described in the patent.

Answer (score 1):

please check the link below for details

http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?CC=US&NR=2005211962A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=&date=20050929&DB=&locale=en_EP